# How to display data from a file on the screen?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, routes

When I go to the route '/ gallery' I get data from the 'posts.json' file. Using 'fs' module and the `read()` method i read data from the file then  write it to `this.pictures` array. But when I navigate to '/ gallery' route,  the new data file is downloaded named 'gallery'.

**I need read data from file and display it in screen,not dowload new file:) Please help solve this problem**

**app.js:**

```js
const express = require('express');
const  Database =  require('./db');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const  db = new Database();

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/gallery', (req, res) => {
    db.read();
    res.send(db.pictures);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`);
});
```

**db.js:**

```js
class Database {

    constructor(){
        this.fs = require('fs');
        this.pictures = [];

    }

    read() {
        this.fs.readFile('./posts.json', (err, data)=> {
            if(err) {
                throw err;
            }else {
               this.pictures = data;
            }
        });
    }
}

module.exports = Database;
```

Comment: read() is asynchronous but you don't wait for it to finish before calling db.pictures(). what happens if you log db.pictures() to the console before res.send()

Comment: when i log db.read() i had - undefined
when log db.pictues i had - []

Comment: Also you should move the require(fs) outside of the constructor. all require statements are cached in node so having it in the constructor is pointless. Having up top immediately lets you and other devs know what the modules dependencies are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a couple of things that I can see that are wrong with your code here. Your calling an async method in your constructor which you shouldn't. Are you planning on calling read() only once or very frequently? I would take a look into NodeJS constructors and also brush up on async practices. 
Having said that, here is the way i would possibly set up the code you have

App.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const  Database =  require('./db');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const  db = new Database();

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/gallery', (req, res) => {
    // Just call pictures. This will call read everytime it needs pictures - This may not work if you only need to call it once per app life   
     db.pictures(function(err,data){
        if(err){
           throw(err)
        }else{
           res.send(data)
         }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`);
});
```

db.js - This is where your app needs more work

```js
const fs = require('fs')
class Database {
  pictures (callback) {
    return this.read(callback)
  }
  //Read the file from the server. Make sure to specify utf-8 to read as a string basically
  read (callback) {
    return fs.readFile('./posts.json', 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
       if (err) {
          throw err
       } else {
          callback(null,data)
       }
    }) 
  }
}

module.exports = Database
```

If you are only planning on calling read() once and only at the start of the app, its possible to call readFileSync which is a synchronous version of the file you have called. Because Node is [blocking](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/), you don't want to do to this in the middle of an app, but it is an option to read config files etc on app startup.

Another way using promises:

```js
const express = require('express')
const Database = require('./db')

const app = express()
const port = 3000
const db = new Database()

app.use(express.json())

app.get('/gallery', (req, res) => {
  db.pictures().then(data => {
    res.send(data)
  })
})
console.log(port)
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`)
})
```

db.js

```js
const fs = require('fs')
class Database {
  pictures () {
    return this.read()
  }
  read (cb) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.readFile('./posts.json', 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err)
        } else {
          resolve(data)
        }
      })
    })
  }
}

module.exports = Database
```

Comment: change my code for  you example,  but any result on screen

Comment: data   from posts.json is not  displayed on the screen

Comment: Are you seeing the data come back in dev tools?

Comment: when i log data i see it in  node console,  but not in the dev tools

Comment: sorry massive brainfart. Been using promises for so long i got them confused with this. try the newly changed code.